# Knight and knaves

Tags: logic

I have these in my lecture notes, its about the rules where knights always tell the truth and knaves always lie:

- If A says “The statement ‘there is gold on the island’ and the statement ‘I
  am a knight’ are either both true or both false” he is asserting A ≡ G
  where A is the assertion A is a knight and G the assertion there is gold
  on the Island.
- Any assertion by a knave has the same truth value as A therefore:

A ≡ (A ≡ G)

(A ≡ A) ≡ G

true ≡ G
[image]

Since A ≡ (A ≡ G), it can only be the first case or third case. Hence, G is
true and A can be true or false

The notes end here, I just don't understand why is it not possible for A to lie about being a knight and about gold being on the island, I mean it just shows that A is a knave, it should still be legal, even though the truth table says its illegal for the that to happen(last row), I just can't internalize why.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a practical programming problem. It *might* be on-topic on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic

Comment: Is A a person or a proposition, you are using them interchangeably

Comment: That is the confusing part, but I believe A is the person as well as the proposition.